# load an image in a particular element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a place for the main photo (id = "main") and other photos in the table (id = "pic+1(2,3,4,5,6)"). I would like to click on a photo with id = "pic *n*" and to load it in the element with id "main". How to realize this?

Also I have an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null.

Here is my code:

```
<img id="main" src="">

galery(dir){
...

...
    function createPreview() {
        var f = document.createElement("table");
        var row = f.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < count ; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(j);
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = dir + '/' + j + ".jpg";
            img.width = "100";
            img.id = 'pic' + j;
            cell.appendChild(img);
        }
        document.body.appendChild(f);
    }

    document.getElementById(this.pic).onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('main').src = this.src;
    }


...
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: `this.pic` clearly isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Help me! I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `var row = f.insertRow();` where is "f" defined?

Comment: Neither do we, as we have no idea what `this` is, and certainly not what `this.pic` is supposed to be ?

Comment: I define f - var f = document.createElement("table");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your code has many errors and misunderstandings on how js works here is some simple code that solves this issue

```
  //fake an image directory
    var count = 3;
    var dir = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/300/abstract/'

    //setup a table
    var f = document.createElement("table");
    var row = f.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      imagepath = dir + j;
      cell.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imagepath + '" width="100" onclick="showmain(' + j + ')">';
    }
    document.body.appendChild(f);

    //change imagesrc in main tag
    function showmain(image) {
      document.getElementById('main').src = dir + image;
    }
```

This is the most basic (noob) thing you do with javascript.

I strongly suggest you read some more tutorials before coming back with such basic questions.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0BYlfsvl8aBLtywoJuOP?p=preview).

No onload handler, so the script is at the end of the page.

Comment: I have an error - Uncaught ReferenceError: showmain is not defined, because my main function is function galery(dir){} Code in my post there is in the galery(dir). How to call showmain in this function?

Comment: Doh, just keep showmain outside of any function or onload handler. best place is at the end of your script tag, just before you do </script>. Or if want be absolutely sure add another script section. You can have as many as you want.

Comment: But I want same "onclick="function(){document.getElementById('main').src = dir + image;}"" but it don't work.

Comment: Just look at the usage and count of the quotes in this question. How do you think javascript should know where a string starts and where it ends? Read something about escaping quote.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your code:

1) You define var f inside the function, so its scope is inside the function. But then you try to get it  outside the function with `document.body.appendChild(f);` which doesn't work. you should move `document.body.appendChild(f);` inside the function.

2) Then you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null.` because `document.getElementById(this.pic)` returns null. this.pic returns no id.

3) close your `img tag`.

4) You have 2 extra `}`

And I am sure there are more if you show us all your code.

Comment: How to close img tag?

Comment: How to call function image, which it clicked?

Comment: `<img id="main" src=""/>`

Comment: AHAHA))) How to call function image, which it clicked?